# Microsoft Graph Api - Appointment Bookings dateTime Issue

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api

So i've been using the microsoft bookings Beta Api getting the List from this URL:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/Contosolunchdelivery@M365B489948.onmicrosoft.com/appointments
```

it works fine except i need to get the start -> dateTime and end -> dateTime for the specific appointment but its returning wrong start dates? even though when i go to bookings i clearly put the start time.

This is what the JSON-Example should looks like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#bookingBusinesses('Contosolunchdelivery%40M365B489948.onmicrosoft.com')/appointments",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADKoAAA=",
            "selfServiceAppointmentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "customerId": "829e3cb5-3d4d-4319-a8de-1953aedaa166",
            "customerName": "Bob Kelly",
            "customerEmailAddress": "bobk@tailspintoys.com",
            "customerPhone": "213-555-0108",
            "customerNotes": null,
            "serviceId": "57da6774-a087-4d69-b0e6-6fb82c339976",
            "serviceName": "Catered bento",
            "duration": "PT30M",
            "preBuffer": "PT5M",
            "postBuffer": "PT10M",
            "priceType": "fixedPrice",
            "price": 10,
            "serviceNotes": null,
            "optOutOfCustomerEmail": false,
            "staffMemberIds": [],
            "invoiceAmount": 10,
            "invoiceId": "1002",
            "invoiceStatus": "open",
            "invoiceUrl": "theInvoiceUrl",
            "customerLocation": {
                "displayName": "Customer",
                "locationEmailAddress": null,
                "locationUri": "",
                "locationType": null,
                "uniqueId": null,
                "uniqueIdType": null,
                "address": {
                    "type": "home",
                    "postOfficeBox": "",
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "countryOrRegion": "",
                    "postalCode": ""
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "altitude": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "accuracy": null,
                    "altitudeAccuracy": null
                }
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2018-04-30T13:00:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2018-04-30T13:30:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "serviceLocation": {
                "displayName": "Customer location (987 Third Avenue, Buffalo, NY 98052, USA)",
                "locationEmailAddress": null,
                "locationUri": "",
                "locationType": null,
                "uniqueId": null,
                "uniqueIdType": null,
                "address": {
                    "type": "home",
                    "postOfficeBox": "",
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "countryOrRegion": "",
                    "postalCode": ""
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "altitude": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "accuracy": null,
                    "altitudeAccuracy": null
                }
            },
            "reminders": [],
            "invoiceDate": {
                "dateTime": "2018-04-30T13:30:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMkADKnAAA=",
            "selfServiceAppointmentId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "customerId": "7ed53fa5-9ef2-4f2f-975b-27447440bc09",
            "customerName": "Jordan Miller",
            "customerEmailAddress": "jordanm@contoso.com",
            "customerPhone": "213-555-0199",
            "customerNotes": null,
            "serviceId": "57da6774-a087-4d69-b0e6-6fb82c339976",
            "serviceName": "Catered bento",
            "duration": "PT30M",
            "preBuffer": "PT5M",
            "postBuffer": "PT10M",
            "priceType": "fixedPrice",
            "price": 10,
            "serviceNotes": null,
            "optOutOfCustomerEmail": false,
            "staffMemberIds": [],
            "invoiceAmount": 10,
            "invoiceId": "1001",
            "invoiceStatus": "open",
            "invoiceUrl": "theInvoiceUrl",
            "customerLocation": {
                "displayName": "Customer",
                "locationEmailAddress": null,
                "locationUri": "",
                "locationType": null,
                "uniqueId": null,
                "uniqueIdType": null,
                "address": {
                    "type": "home",
                    "postOfficeBox": "",
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "countryOrRegion": "",
                    "postalCode": ""
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "altitude": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "accuracy": null,
                    "altitudeAccuracy": null
                }
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-01T12:00:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-01T12:30:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "serviceLocation": {
                "displayName": "Customer location (123 First Avenue, Buffalo, NY 98052, USA)",
                "locationEmailAddress": null,
                "locationUri": "",
                "locationType": null,
                "uniqueId": null,
                "uniqueIdType": null,
                "address": {
                    "type": "home",
                    "postOfficeBox": "",
                    "street": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "countryOrRegion": "",
                    "postalCode": ""
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "altitude": null,
                    "latitude": null,
                    "longitude": null,
                    "accuracy": null,
                    "altitudeAccuracy": null
                }
            },
            "reminders": [],
            "invoiceDate": {
                "dateTime": "2018-05-01T12:30:00.0000000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is what im getting for the start and end date time:

```
    start:
        dateTime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
         timeZone: "Etc/UTC"


    end: 
dateTime: "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z"
timeZone: "Etc/UTC"
```

I dont know what i'm doing wrong, i'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the time wrong on `/appointments`? Or is it happening with `appointments/{appointmentsid}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason using this URL:

```
GET /bookingBusinesses/{id}/calendarView?start={start-value}&end={end-value}
```

did end up giving me the exact results i was looking with correct time and everything the list appointments url was giving me.

I guess that's why this is still in BETA